# How should I resolve merge conflicts in autogenerated RBI files?

Tags: sorbet

It seems like some of the merge conflicts are even in an errors.txt file...

Is it ok to just delete all the autogenerated files and then regenerate them?

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can (and should) delete the autogenerated files and then regenerate them. You *could* manually resolve the conflicts, but that's error-prone and could cause weird issues if you mess anything up.